# Xcode Build Error 'Undefined Symbols for Architecture arm64'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_AES_ctr128_encrypt", referenced from:
      _csrEncryptCTR in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
  "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init", referenced from:
      _csrEncryptData in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrEncryptCCM in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrDecryptCCM in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrDecryptData in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrEncryptCBC in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrDecryptCBC in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
  "_HMAC_CTX_init", referenced from:
      _csrGenerateChallenge in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrGenerateSessionKey in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrComputeHMACSHA256 in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
  "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup", referenced from:
      _csrEncryptData in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrEncryptCCM in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrDecryptCCM in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrDecryptData in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrEncryptCBC in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrDecryptCBC in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
  "_HMAC_CTX_cleanup", referenced from:
      _csrGenerateChallenge in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrGenerateSessionKey in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
      _csrComputeHMACSHA256 in CSRmeshRestClient(csr_mesh_crypto.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried set excluded frameworks (arm64) in Xcode build settings, but still getting same error. Does any one having idea on this ?

Comment: What would you find if you ask Google or whoever about "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64"?

Comment: Most of the answers are suggesting to set excluded architectures to arm64.

Comment: I tried that but still getting same error.

Comment: I used to get this error with OpenSSL. It was because OpenSSL version that i was using was newer but my xcode and macOS versions were old. For a quick fix i decreased OpenSSL version until error no longer appears. Later i updated OS and Xcode to newer versions. Then with new OpenSSL, there was no issue. May be you also having the same problem with your library you are using.